# ¿Cómo puedo devolver fecha con formato "dia/mes/año" en Java?

Tags: java, date

Tengo que hacer un método que reciba un objeto tipo `java.util.Date` y devuelva la fecha con formato **dia/mes/año**.

Comment: Para dar formatos a fechas, puedes usar la clase [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase SimpleDateFormat para darle ese formato, así:

```
//Aquí colocas tu objeto tipo Date
Date myDate = new Date();

//Aquí obtienes el formato que deseas
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(myDate));
```

Con cualquier otra duda puedes consultar la documentación de esta clase [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Pdta: Esta pregunta se encuentra resuelta en inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy).

Comment: Gracias Julián por tu rápida respuesta

Answer (score 5):

Aunque tu ejercicio pida un **Date**, es bueno saber que se está comenzando a migrar a partir de Java 8 a la librerías de fechas **javax.time** y en vez de **Date** utilizar el objeto **LocalDate**.

```
Date fecha = Date();
LocalDate fecha1 = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate fecha2 = LocalDate.of(año,mes,dia);
```

> **[JAVA 8]** Formato Día/Mes/Año: "dd/LL/yyyy"

```
String obtenerFechaFormateada(LocalDate fecha, String formato) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formato);
    return fecha.format(dtf);
}
```

> **[JAVA < 8]** Formato Día/Mes/Año: "dd-MM-yyyy"

```
String obtenerFechaFormateada(Date fecha, String formato) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
    return sdf.format(fecha);
}
```

Enlaces de interés

- [Introducing the New Date and Time API for JDK 8](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time)
- [Java 8 Date Time API Example Tutorial – LocalDate, Instant, LocalDateTime, Parse and Format](http://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-time-api-example-tutorial-localdate-instant-localdatetime-parse-and-format)

Comment: El paquete es `java.time`. El artículo que mencionas es del 2012 cuando habían pruebas sobre lo que sería Java 8. Te recomiendo siempre poner la documentación oficial primero, luego artículos (de preferencia en español) que expliquen el tema.

Comment: Ahora que leo la pregunta, en ninguna parte del código de Java 8 estás recibiendo el tipo `java.util.Date` que es el foco de la pregunta. Primero debes convertir el `Date` a `LocalDate`, luego aplicar lo que mencionas.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con `SimpleDateFormat();` con ese le puedes dar el formato que gustes.

**Ejemplo:**

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Para llamar la funcion:

```
        Date fecha_ini = forma1.parse(fecha);
```

La MM en mayusculas si la pones en minusculas la toma como minuto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public String getFechaMod(){
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return sf.format(fechaMod);
}
```

Creamos un método de tipo string. Declaramos `simpledateformat` el cual nos deja personalizar el formato en que deseamos mostrar la fechar *así como se muestra en este ejemplo*.

Answer (score 0):

Si el método quedaría como sigue:

```
  public Date devolverFecha(Date fechaEntrada) { 

    SimpleDateFormat formato = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
    String fechaString = fechaEntrada.toString(); // Convierte Date a String
    Date miFecha = formato.parse(fechaString); // convierte String a Date
    return miFecha;

  }
```

Este es una solución propuesta